# How do i sort strings into linked lists according to their initials?

Tags: c++, linked-list

Hello everyone so this is my first question here.I will try to explain my problem as briefly as i can.So i am trying to sort a taken string into 26 different lists according to their initials.I don't know if this is a proper approach since i am only a student yet.When i run this code i get the following error which i could not find any solution for.

error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'item' used

Here is my node struct and my linked list is just as any other linked list class.

template

```
struct nodeType
{
    int wCount;
    Type info;
    nodeType<Type> *link;
};
```

So my question is why do i get this error and is there any better approach for my problem.(By the way this is just a part of what i am trying to do normally i should be reading a processed text file and inserting every word into a list according to their initials and increase their count if they exist in the list.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "unorderedLinkedListType.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

 int main()
{
    unorderedLinkedList<string> listA, listB, listC, listD, listE, listF, listG,
        listH, listI, listJ, listK, listL, listM, listN, listO, listP, listQ, listR,
        listS, listT, listU, listV, listW, listX, listY, listZ;


    nodeType<string> *item; // Node Definition
    item->info = "trying";
    item->link = NULL;
    item->wCount = 0;


    char first;                // Taking the initial of a string
    first = item->info[0];


    switch (first) // Switch case for insertion to lists
    {
    case 'a': if (listA.search(item->info)){ item->wCount++; }
              else { listA.insertFirst(item->info); }
              break;
    case 'b': if (listB.search(item->info)){ item->wCount++; }
              else { listB.insertFirst(item->info); }
              break;
    case 'c': if (listC.search(item->info)){ item->wCount++; }
              else { listC.insertFirst(item->info); }
              break;
    case 'd': if (listD.search(item->info)){ item->wCount++; }
              else { listD.insertFirst(item->info); }
              break;
    case 'e': if (listE.search(item->info)){ item->wCount++; }
              else { listE.insertFirst(item->info); }
              break;
    case 'f': if (listF.search(item->info)){ item->wCount++; }
              else { listF.insertFirst(item->info); }
              break;
    case 'g': if (listG.search(item->info)){ item->wCount++; }
              else { listG.insertFirst(item->info); }
              break;
    case 'h': if (listH.search(item->info)){ item->wCount++; }
              else { listH.insertFirst(item->info); }
              break;
    case 'i': if (listI.search(item->info)){ item->wCount++; }
              else { listI.insertFirst(item->info); }
              break;
    case 'j': if (listJ.search(item->info)){ item->wCount++; }
              else { listJ.insertFirst(item->info); }
              break;
    case 'k': if (listK.search(item->info)){ item->wCount++; }
              else { listK.insertFirst(item->info); }
              break;
    case 'l': if (listL.search(item->info)){ item->wCount++; }
              else { listL.insertFirst(item->info); }
              break;
    case 'm': if (listM.search(item->info)){ item->wCount++; }
              else { listM.insertFirst(item->info); }
              break;
    case 'n': if (listN.search(item->info)){ item->wCount++; }
              else { listN.insertFirst(item->info); }
              break;
    case 'o': if (listO.search(item->info)){ item->wCount++; }
              else { listO.insertFirst(item->info); }
              break;
    case 'p': if (listP.search(item->info)){ item->wCount++; }
              else { listP.insertFirst(item->info); }
              break;
    case 'q': if (listQ.search(item->info)){ item->wCount++; }
              else { listQ.insertFirst(item->info); }
              break;
    case 'r': if (listR.search(item->info)){ item->wCount++; }
              else { listR.insertFirst(item->info); }
              break;
    case 's': if (listS.search(item->info)){ item->wCount++; }
              else { listS.insertFirst(item->info); }
              break;
    case 't': if (listT.search(item->info)){ item->wCount++; }
              else { listT.insertFirst(item->info); }
              break;
    case 'u': if (listU.search(item->info)){ item->wCount++; }
              else { listU.insertFirst(item->info); }
              break;
    case 'v': if (listV.search(item->info)){ item->wCount++; }
              else { listV.insertFirst(item->info); }
              break;
    case 'w': if (listW.search(item->info)){ item->wCount++; }
              else { listW.insertFirst(item->info); }
              break;
    case 'x': if (listX.search(item->info)){ item->wCount++; }
              else { listX.insertFirst(item->info); }
              break;
    case 'y': if (listY.search(item->info)){ item->wCount++; }
              else { listY.insertFirst(item->info); }
              break;
    case 'z': if (listZ.search(item->info)){ item->wCount++; }
              else { listZ.insertFirst(item->info); }
              break;
    }

    listT.print(); // Printing the listT to try out my code


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: because item is not initialized and keeps garbage, but you try to dereference it

Comment: `nodeType<string> *item;   item->info = "trying";`  You're writing linked list classes, and you didn't recognize this obvious error?  Hopefully it's just an oversight and not a misunderstanding of how pointers work.  Also, you could have used an array of 26 linked lists instead of declaring 26 separate variables.

Comment: Now i see the problem i should have allocated it a new space like this.               item = new nodeType<string>; Thank you all for your time

Comment: @FurkanKılıçaslan Usage of arrays:  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39a2ea394a0fcaf0  That entire `switch` is reduced to a single 4 or 5 line block of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nodeType<string> *item;` is a pointer to an item. But you never allocated the item and initialized the pointer. Please use a [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/map/) instead of this creepy switch statement and 26 lists.

```
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map< char, unorderedLinkedList<string> > listMap;

    nodeType<string> *item = new nodeType<string>();
    item->info = "trying";
    item->link = NULL;
    item->wCount = 0;

    char first; 
    first = item->info[0];

    if (listMap[first].search(item->info))
    { 
        item->wCount++;
    }
    else
    { 
        listMap[first].insertFirst(item->info);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion i have never used maps before but i will try to learn and implement and about the error again thank you i should have been more careful it was an obvious mistake.

Comment: Hey again gernot so i am still working on this project and i wanted to ask you if there is any other way of doing this by only writing my own code? So i can get a practice of a such situation.